# Is it common to say 'Kilo' to mean 'Kilogram'?

Tags: word-usage

In my language(Serbian) it is normal to say *kilo* and mean *kilogram* because the use is most common there and it is like a short version. I know that kilo means one thousand and that it is not correct because kilo is just a prefix but we do it.
My question:

Is it in English common (acceptable) to say kilo and mean kilogram?

Comment: In the UK and Ireland, it is acceptable to use *kilo* in place of *kilogram*. This may not be the case in the USA, since it does not use the metric system, or other English-speaking countries.

Comment: It would generally be understood in the US (especially since news reports of drug busts often mention *kilos* of some drugs).

Comment: @Mick In fairness, the UK doesn't fully embrace the metric system, and the US doesn't fully reject it. British speed limits are in miles per hour, beer is sold in pints, body weight is in stone and pounds, and so on. And in the U.S., many government and industry standards are in metric, only converted to customary units for the delicate sensibilities of the public, thus a bottle of soda identical to one sold in Canada as a 500ml bottle is sold in the U.S. as a 16.9oz bottle, and no one ever asks why the bizarre quantity of 16.9 fluid ounces would have been chosen.

Comment: I speak Serbian too! As a speaker of both languages, I use "kilo" exclusively in Serbia.

Comment: I am from Spain,but I live in the US currently,and I am pretty sure kilo is ok in the US.

Comment: @choster: If I'm not mistaken, the US was the first country (or at least one of the first) to use a decimal system for money, and it may end up being the last to use a decimal (e.g. metric) system for other measures. Britain is/was a bit the other way around: metric system generally, long ago, money not so much. ;-)

Comment: @Drew USA: [decimal money 1792](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coinage_Act_of_1792), later: [metric system 1799](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_system).  ;-)  BTW: the US 5 cent coin weight exactly [5 grams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nickel_(United_States_coin))

Comment: @choster tell me about it! Trying to compare weights and there is seems to be just 1 country to commonly use stone: the U.K...

Comment: Short answer: yes.

Comment: @chux: Yes, that's just as I thought. But when was *British* adoption of the metric system? Was it 1854, with the (British) Decimal Association as described in section *Decimal multiples* of your second reference? It wasn't 1799, was it?

Comment: I am from the U.S. , if I hear kilo i will assume kilogram.

Comment: Without weight context, amongst English speaking sailors and others, "kilo" is simply the letter [K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet)

Comment: Just as reference, in Spanish is the same as Serbian

Comment: Technically yes, but I'd recommend only using it to prefix whatever you're describing. In the US it is common to associate certain vague metric measurements with illegal activity like the drug trade. I.e:  "Yeah dude, I bought like 4 kilos!" Can easily be interpreted as having bought illicit substances. Instead I'd recommend saying "Yeah dude, I bought like 4 kilos of concrete mix!" or whatever is applicable.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

*Kilo* as a short form of *kilogram* dates back to at least 1870, according to the OED, long before Britain adopted the metric system. You can find it in American dictionaries as well; AHD [simply puts it](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=kilo) as

> **ki·lo** *n. pl.* **ki·los** A kilogram.

and Merriam-Webster consider this its [primary definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kilo).

The OED also notes that *kilo* can be short for *kilometre*; however, in current usage, this is unlikely to be the assumed meaning outside of narrow contexts. If nothing else, *kilo* has been reinforced among the public as a unit of mass due to its common usage in television police shows involving drug smuggling.

In more formal communications, I would still advise spelling out *kilograms* (or  using *kg*) to avoid any ambiguity, however.

Comment: Weirdly for distance the single letter *k* seems to be the most common abbreviation. *I ran a 10 k last night.*

Comment: @k1eran That's true, but much more so for *5K* and *10K* (common standards) than for arbitrary distances.  I've also heard *K* used for kilograms in a gym context.

Comment: Pretty much anyone (at least in the US) wanting to abbreviate *kilometer* would use "klick".

Comment: I don't know how it is in Serbian, but note that in English you should use the multiple when talking about more than 1 kilogram. So it is "a three-kilo bag" but "the bag weighs 3 _kilos_". (Just wanted to stress this because in my native language the plural of _kilo_ is _kilo_).

Comment: @k1eran I think “k” is generally used as an arbitrary 1000 multiplier — certainly not just for distances. Compare “he’s making over 100K a year” etc.

Comment: Now I feel sheltered for using *kilo* much more often of flour and sugar than of drugs.

Comment: @chrylis As an American, I have literally never heard anybody use "klick" outside of military (or paramilitary) contexts.

Comment: I'm a native English speaker, living in Finland, a metric EU country. *Kilo* (plural *kilos*) is pretty normal in both the local language and when speaking English, and is used for both *kilometer* and *kilogram*. *Klick* for *kilometer* seems to be an American/military thing. When speaking English, people will commonly say *five ks* (pronounced "kays") for distance, weight, computing (kilobytes), science (Kelvin) or anywhere else that a *k-* value can be abbreviated.

Comment: @chrylis Not heard "klick" outside of war films, as a Brit.

Comment: As an aside, interestingly, the medical professionals around here (NYC, US), particularly veterinary, all seem to say "kigs" for kilograms, as a pronunciation of the abbreviation "kg". I hear this from a wide range of professionals, not just the neighborhood vet or physician, but surgeons, medical directors, committee heads, published authors, etc. I was surprised and confused the first time I heard it, but it pops up consistently in that context.

Comment: "klick" is pretty common for kilometer in Canada if you ask how far away something is. How far is Toronto from Windsor? It's about 400 klicks.

Comment: @Sabre I've heard it used whenever people were actually talking about kilometers. I'm sure it's highly relevant that fields that use the metric system to measure distances in the United States have a strong representation from former military members, and that's almost certainly its source.

Comment: @flith I'm not sure what you meant, but I'm a native Finnish speaker living in Finland and I've never ever heard anyone use _kilo_ for kilometer in Finnish, but it's the most common word for kilogram (actually people very rarely say the full _kilogram_ when talking about mass). I'd also be very surprised if a Finn used _kilo_ for kilometer even in English.

Comment: @jik, you're right... I reorganised my comment a couple of times, and by the time I added in the bit about both, I realised that I was thinking about one thing and writing another. By that point, I'd passed the five-minute-edit limit for comments. Ironically, my train went right past Kilo on the way home.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, Americans know the word *kilo*. However, this word is not meaningful to them the way it is to you.  This is because they don’t have any common reference points that would allow them to immediately understand how much something is in kilos.  If you told them something was 5 kilos, they couldn't tell you whether that was like a bag of sweets or a tunafish sandwich or a gallon of milk or a bag of potatoes or can of gas or their mother-in-law. Since nothing is measured in that here, it is just a random foreign number. It would be like telling you that something was 5 acres or 5 feet or 5 ounces: you'd know the word, but the quantity would not be something you could associate with anything concrete in your own life.

So no matter whether you said *kilos* or *kilograms*, many Americans would blank if you used these units in your conversations with them. It isn't a unit of measurement that is used here. It's a foreign language.

Some might think when you said *kilos*, you were talking about *kilometers* not *kilograms*, and many would be unable to fathom how much whatever you were talking about really was even if they figured out that you meant mass-*qua*-weight.  They have nothing to compare it with so it’s just random meaningless numbers to them.

You should therefore always convert to American measurements when talking to Americans, just as you would convert Serbian to English. That means you should convert kilograms to pounds.

This does not apply to technical conversations with scientists accustomed to using these units. But the overwhelming majority of Americans will have no idea what you are talking about, just as though you were talking to them in Serbian instead of in English.

Comment: *At this time, only three countries - Burma, Liberia, and the US - have not adopted the International System of Units (SI, or metric system) as their official system of weights and measures. [...]  The US is the only industrialized nation that does not mainly use the metric system in its commercial and standards activities, but there is increasing acceptance in science, medicine, government, and many sectors of industry.* https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/appendix/appendix-g.html It seems a little crazy American general public still using horrendous imperial units :-)

Comment: @k1eran What nobody understands is that these are 330 million people who never have to deal with anything else. It's what they've always used. They have no reason to stop when nothing around them is in these foreign numbers, and when most of them will never leave their country anyway. If you don't live here, it is impossible for you to understand how this works to come from a giant country where you never have to use foreign figures. It doesn't matter to them what other people are doing: it does not affect them.

Comment: When asking here I was thinking about the "English language" not "in America" :) 
Of course if I am in a country that uses a different system i will convert.

Comment: @MilosRadosavljevic It's an English word, yes; but if you use it on Americans, please do not expect them to truly understand.

Comment: @tchrist I take your point, though I am glad I live somewhere which is *mostly metric* !

Comment: @k1eran It's actually even more complicated, because even in fields like medicine, U.S. conventions may vary from international ones. For instance, serum cholesterol is expressed as milligrams per deciliter in the U.S. whereas it is millimoles per liter elsewhere. And metrication doesn't always simplify things. I spoke to an Australian builder who noted that the standard interior door remains 32×80 inches, except after metrication that became 813×2032mm, which was rounded off in the new standard to 820mm × 2040mm, which means oftentimes, things don't fit quite right.

Comment: @tchrist: comment feels opinionated rather than based on facts. Puerto Rico, a US territory, uses the metric system. Cars in the US have both MPH and Km/h on the dashboard. Nurses delivering babies tell moms they have to be 2 cm dilated before getting an epidural. Military uses the `klick` to refer to a `kilometer`. Yet, to @choster's point, the building industry calls a 2x4 a lumber that is actually cut as a 1 1/2 x 3 1/2 (learned that building a shed). It's a bit all over the board, but Americans have a pretty good sense of the metric system, most round up a meter to a yard which is 3 feet.

Comment: This is factually incorrect. 'kilo' is commonly used in the US to refer to drugs. Examples: 1) [Methuen police seize 15 kilos of fentanyl](http://www.eagletribune.com/news/methuen-police-seize-kilos-of-fentanyl/article_febb6c16-d12c-11e6-9034-3b0d0cb8c4fc.html), 2) [Police Seize 4 Kilos Of Heroin From Bus](http://www.mydailyrecord.com/eedition/featured/2016/10/19/police-seize-4kilos-of-heroin-from-bus/), 3) [York police seize 5 kilos of cocaine](http://www.wistv.com/story/5247523/york-police-seize-5-kilos-of-cocaine). "Police seize kilos" has 770,000 hits, many from US websites.

Comment: It's almost a certainty that more Serbian-speaking people live in the USA, than, in any other country, perhaps (but not necessarily) excepting only Serbia.  For any given lesser-known language X - with few, perhaps no, exceptions - you're statistically more likely to be understood in the US than elsewhere.

Comment: @smci You are mistaken: it is not "factually" incorrect. I never said they don't know the word. I said they are unable to get a feel for what a number expressed in kilos means. They have no reference points. It's simply a number. It doesn't mean anything. Fine, so people think something means some amount of drugs. That doesn't say anything. They won't know what 17 kilos of something is, or 200. It has no guideposts. Unless, I suppose, they're drug dealers.

Comment: @tchrist - I'd say you're mostly correct, but it's a mixed bag. Yes, I'd have trouble telling you my weight in kilos, or my height in cm, without doing a little math in my head first. However, there are few exceptions where Americans are well-versed in metric measurements. Being an avid runner, I'm fully aware of the length of a 10K, and nearly every American knows how much 2 liters is, thanks to the soda industry's decision to sell in 2-liter bottles. Automobile engines also often use metric measurements, as does the pharmaceutical industry.

Comment: Worth noticing, perhaps: The [Florida High School State Athletic Association](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/01/19/sports/floridas-high-schools-field-events-metric.html?_r=0) has just switched to metric measurements for its track and field events. Every baby step matters.

Comment: @John 1 metre is approximately 39 inches (3 feet 3 inches) - so you would be rounding *down* when you equate 1 metre to approx. 1 yard. P.S. *metre* is the British spelling: in BrE, a *meter* is a measuring device, e.g. a gas meter, or an electricity meter.

Comment: @TrevorD correct it's round down, what I meant to say was americans approximate a `meter` to `3 yards`. P.S. to your P.S.: `meter` is the correct spelling of a `metre` in american english.