# When is it okay to use "kilo" in American English?

Tags: american-english

I was watching episodes of a documentary series called *Drug Lords* with one of the big video streaming providers.

Strangely for me, while the whole documentary was narrated with American accent *and* the overall focus was on the fight of the US government/DEA against drug trafficking, the narrator used **kilo/kilos** a lot during his voiceover when referring to quantities of the drugs in question.

That struck me as odd, given the customary use of ounces and pounds when describing weights in the US.

Is the use of **kilo** in the context of drug trafficking commonplace and therefore to be expected, or would this - from the point of view of a native speaker from the US - be considered odd in any way?

Essentially what I am interested to find out is whether there are specific areas aside from the typical scientific use of [SI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units) units where it's customary to use metric units or whether this was perhaps done in order to appeal to international audiences. After all even NASA and NASAs contractors [have been known to use US units](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Mars_Climate_Orbiter&oldid=817206911#Cause_of_failure) for scientific projects, so to me the use of **kilo** was unusual enough to ask here.

Comment: Despite the fact that the U.S. uses old-style weights and measures, Americans are aware that the metric system does exist. Most Americans know very well what a kilo is, though they might have to get kilos translated to pounds and vice versa..

Comment: In the drugs world - so I am informed - the use of 'kilo' is as global as the use of 'carat' in the diamond trade.

Comment: @NigelJ: thanks. If you could provide an authoritative source for it I would accept that as answer.

Comment: Since the words pounds and ounces (in this form) originated and are still often used in the UK, I'm intrigued by the label 'US units'.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/370463/is-it-common-to-say-kilo-to-mean-kilogram

Comment: I don’t have an authoritative source at hand either, but like @Nigel, I too recognise the use of _kilo_ when referring specifically to drugs. My ‘source’ is probably mostly watching CSI and other crime shows on TV.

Comment: ***Take 1 Kilogram of Heroin supplied by a dealer each day***. That would enable the dealer to make 10,000 ‘wraps’ or £10 bags.  https://www.ersourocu.org.uk/31/section.aspx/21/1_kg_heroin

Comment: It should be stated that, to what is probably a substantial minority of Americans, 'kilo" refers *only* to a quantity of illicit drugs, and hence saying, eg, "a kilo of sugar" could be taken as a winking reference to said contraband.  It is probably better to use "kilogram" if you're hoping to avoid such an inference.

Comment: @user159691 that link provides excellent coverage of the topic, including several mentions of the use of *kilo* specifically in the context of drugs. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[Kilo:](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/kilo) is used as a unit of measure in international drugs traffic:

> 1870, shortening of kilogram. **Slang shortening *key* (in drug trafficking) is attested from 1968.**

(Etymonline)

Usage examples:

> ***To produce a kilogram (2.2 pounds) of pure cocaine*** requires about a ton of fresh coca leaf, Wainwright told Business Insider. "It then gets dried out, it weighs a bit less, but that ton of leaf to start with costs only about $400 or $500 in Colombia," he said.

[businessinsider.com](http://www.businessinsider.com/how-much-does-cocaine-cost-in-the-us-2016-10?IR=T)

> ***"A kilo of cocaine, current price around £50,000, if you double that kilo with benzocaine and you have two kilos*** the dealer could then probably knock that out for something in the region of £80,000 to £90,000. So as you can see the profit margin on their initial outlay is significant."

[BBC.com](http://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-11177126)

Comment: BBB? Not American [ABC](http://abc.go.com/) but British BBC.

Comment: More generally, you could say that the choice of weight unit is domain-specific, and drug smuggling is one of the domains which favours metric measures.  There are lots of others.